# Shins hurt when running

Tags: running, pain, walking

I have been slowly getting back into shape. Started with my diet and have since added walking for half an hour most days. I haven't been tracking my weight because I am not so concerned by weight as actual fat. I have lost almost 2 clothing sizes.

Recently I have been starting to jog as well as walk, slowly increasing the distance I jog. That has been going well and I have also tried doing short sprints in between long walks just to shake things up a bit. In addition to losing fat I also want to get back to a reasonable fitness level.

When doing short sprints I notice a rather sharp pain in my shins. I am wondering what this is and if it will go away as I continue to get fitter and lose weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not medically qualified, but sounds like it may be Shin Splints: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_splints

Here's a Runner's World article with more information on them: http://www.runnersworld.co.uk/beating-injury/shinsplints---how-to-beat-them/234.html

I would still see a Doctor to confirm.